# Which widget can I use to have like this image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I searched in flutter widget to find a widget that is same as this one but I didn't find how can I do like this one?[image with text in bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOfs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]try the code below, its working and tested

```
Center(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
                'https://images.pexels.com/photos/433539/pexels-photo-433539.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=bali-beautiful-beauty-433539.jpg&fm=jpg'),
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              left: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  'ImageText',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.black54,
                height: 60,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help it worked

Answer (score 0):

You could use Stack Widget. This would look something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.network('www.somesite.com/some_image_url.png'),
    Container(
      color: Colors.black12
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text('ImageText'),
    ),
  ]
)
```